# Dynamics CRM 2013, redirect on "no user exists" error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

When new users join my organization, they may need to have their manager request access to CRM for them. I want to gather information from them in a form before handling the request.

When unauthorized users attempt to access CRM, they see an error message that says: "No Microsoft Dynamics CRM user exists with the specified domain name and user ID"

How can I redirect them from that error message to a form of my own design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to redirect them.  The only way you could do it would be  to give your users a custom url that points to another webpage with Windows Authentication.  Then you could query CRM to see if the user exists, if it does, then you could redirect them, if it doesn't then you can display / do whatever you'd like.

I wouldn't recommend this because users that navigate to it via Office 365 would not hit your custom website.